# Sqoop - Import - Query subcommand - Parameters in where clause

Tags: import, parameters, where-clause, sqoop

I would like to ask if someone can explain me a Sqoop "query" subcommand functionality in details.

I'm going to use an example of this video:

https://youtu.be/7oZ_CctyS5Q?list=PLf0swTFhTI8rJvGpOp-LujOcpk-Rlz-yE&t=1515

query="select * from orders join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_item_order_id where \$CONDITIONS" \

As we can see, there is a parameter "$CONDITIONS" added in the where condition.

Probably I'm wrong, but after watch the video, I understood the condition will be replaced as "1=1" if the parameter "$CONDITIONS" exists or by "1=0" if don't.

My questions are:

1- Why it is recommend to use the parameter in the Where clause of the "query" subcommand

2- What happen if we really have a WHERE clause in a parameter which we want to use in the "query" subcommand and not in the "where" subcommand?

Appreciate your help on this,

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not exactly understood your queries, however let me try to answer. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

**1- Why it is recommend to use the parameter in the Where clause of the "query" subcommand**

SQOOP imports data in parallel from RDBMS. You can specify no of map tasks (parallel process) to use to perform the import by using the `-m` or `--num-mappers` argument. By default 4 map tasks will be used by SQOOP.

For example, if you had a table with a primary key column of `order_id` whose minimum value was 0 and maximum value was 1000, and SQOOP was directed to use 4 tasks, SQOOP would run four processes which each execute SQL statements of the form 
`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE $CONDITIONS`

Now $CONDITIONS place holder would be replaced as below

1. for map task 1: `order_id >= 0 and order_id < 250`
   and final SQL will look like

   > SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id >= 0 and order_id < 250
2. for map task 2: `order_id >= 250 and order_id < 500`
   and final SQL will look like

   > SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id >= 250 and order_id < 500
3. for map task 3: `order_id >= 500 and order_id < 750`
   and final SQL will look like

   > SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id >= 500 and order_id < 750
4. for map task 4: `order_id >= 750 and order_id < 1001`
   and final SQL will look like

   > SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id >= 750 and order_id < 1001

As you can see $CONDITIONS is a place holder which SQOOP will search and replace with generated values. Please note that specifying $CONDITIONS is mandatory in case no of map tasks is greater than 1.

**2- What happen if we really have a WHERE clause in a parameter which we want to use in the "query" subcommand and not in the "where" subcommand?**

You can simply specify your filter criterion after $CONDITIONS prefixed by `AND`.

For example, if you want to load only those orders where order amount is greater than 100.

> query="select * from orders join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_item_order_id where \$CONDITIONS AND order_amount > 100"

Hope this clarifies !